# How to install programs compressed on linux

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, eclipse

I'm beginner on linux SO, before I was on Windows SO...

In windows I downloaded a program and then run *.exe file, and ready !

In linux, I downloaded this file [Eclipse JEE](https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/1a/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-linux-gtk.tar.gz), but I have not idea how to start this program.

Does it exist some program to install this, or e.g commands rules.

any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to know that gz and tar extensions are compressed file extensions. The most used formats (also rar and zip).

To install Eclipse you need to do the following steps:

1. `tar -zxvf eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-linux-gtk.tar.gz`
2. Then you should execute the installation file. (as seen in the picture below)

You may also need to make the file executable. You can do a right click on the exec file and select "Properties" and then "Permissions" and check "Allow executing file as program"

Another way is using the command line:

```
chmod +x file.ext
```

[image]

I hope you can install it correctly!

To execute Eclipse you can do it in two ways

a) Clicking on the executable file

[image]

b) Run from command line, go to path of installation and run:

```
./eclipse
```

Comment: You might want to add that in some cases the files has to be made executable. This would improve your answer.